# Tkinter dynamic button that calls the function selected in a OptionMenu Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to know how to create a dynamic button that calls the function selected in a OptionMenu Widget.

In the penultimate line [-2], I substituted "command=daily_return" by "command=var" but it does not work.

Any suggestions?
Best

Working code

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox


master = Tk()

myvar_1 = IntVar()
myvar_2 = IntVar()
myvar_3 = StringVar()
myvar_4 = IntVar()
myvar_5 = IntVar()
myvar_6 = IntVar()
myvar_7 = IntVar()
#



def daily_return(*args):
    print "The start date is ", var.get(), "+", myvar_1.get(),"-", myvar_4.get(), "-", myvar_6.get(), "and the end date is", myvar_2.get(),"-", myvar_5.get(), "-", myvar_7.get(), " for the stock ticker:", myvar_3.get(), "."


def cumulative_return(*args):
    print "The start date is ", myvar_1.get(), "the cumulative return."

def value_at_risk(*args):
    print "The start date is ", myvar_1.get(), "the value at risk."



Label(master, text="Start Date (DD-MM-YYYY)").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="End Date (DD-MM-YYYY)").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Stock Ticker").grid(row=2)

##
text_entry_1 = Entry(master, textvariable=myvar_1)
text_entry_1.pack()

text_entry_2 = Entry(master, textvariable=myvar_2)
text_entry_2.pack()

text_entry_3 = Entry(master, textvariable=myvar_3)
text_entry_3.pack()

text_entry_4 = Entry(master, textvariable=myvar_4)
text_entry_4.pack()

text_entry_5 = Entry(master, textvariable=myvar_5)
text_entry_5.pack()

text_entry_6 = Entry(master, textvariable=myvar_6)
text_entry_6.pack()

text_entry_7 = Entry(master, textvariable=myvar_7)
text_entry_7.pack()

#
var = StringVar()
var.set('Choose function')
choices  = ['cumulative_return', 'daily_return', 'value_at_risk']
option = OptionMenu(master, var, *choices)
option.pack()


##
text_entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
text_entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
text_entry_3.grid(row=2, column=1)
text_entry_4.grid(row=0, column=2)
text_entry_5.grid(row=1, column=2)
text_entry_6.grid(row=0, column=3)
text_entry_7.grid(row=1, column=3)
option.grid(row=4, column=0)
sf = "Quant Program"

# 
def quit():
    global root
    master.destroy()


#
master.title("Quant Program")

Button(master, text='Quit', command=quit).grid(row=4, column=4, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=daily_return).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

Comment: Well, there are many problems, but your first problem is that the value of `command=` is meant to be called directly. So if I do `command=foo`, then Tkinter will call `foo()` every time the callback is triggered. So when you do `command=var`, you are telling Tkinter to do `var()` when the callback is triggered. What does calling `var()` even mean in this context?

Comment: I understand that calling var() is wrong. Is there a way to avoid having 10 different buttons to be able to call 10 different functions? Maybe one widget to chose the function and another to call it? Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the simplest solution is Good Enough:

```
def do_something():
    # define a mapping from the choice value to a function name
    func_map = {
        "daily_choices": daily_choices,
        "value_at_risk": value_at_risk,
        "cumulative_return": cumulative_return,
    }
    # using the map, get the function
    function = func_map[var.get()]

    # call the function
    function()

...        
Button(..., command=do_something)
```

Comment: The caption says to avoid doing this but I can't resist. +1 thanks